# Set Shared Preferences data only on install

Tags: android, database, kotlin, sharedpreferences, android-room

I want to set the user name in my application only once per install. We don't have to worry about if the user clears the data or not.

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Check if a key you want to set [is present or not](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences#contains(java.lang.String)), and if not then set it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SharedPreferences or create a database or store user information on the server

```
 private val shared: SharedPreferences = context.applicationContext.getSharedPreferences(
    "Check_Token_User",
    Context.MODE_PRIVATE
)

fun saveToken(token: String?) {
    val editor = shared.edit()
    editor.putString("Token", token)
    editor.apply()
}
```